# Microk8s node not ready - InvalidDiskCapacity

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, microk8s

the node of microk8s does not watn to start. Kube.system pods are stick at pending state. `kubectl describe nodes` says as Warning `InvalidDiskCapacity`. My Server has more than enough resources.

PODS:

```
NAMESPACE            NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
container-registry   registry-7cf58dcdcc-hf8gx                         0/1     Pending   0          5d
kube-system          coredns-588fd544bf-4m6mj                          0/1     Pending   0          5d
kube-system          dashboard-metrics-scraper-db65b9c6f-gj5x4         0/1     Pending   0          5d
kube-system          heapster-v1.5.2-58fdbb6f4d-q6plc                  0/4     Pending   0          5d
kube-system          hostpath-provisioner-75fdc8fccd-6mdvc             0/1     Pending   0          5d
kube-system          kubernetes-dashboard-67765b55f5-8xsh5             0/1     Pending   0          5d
kube-system          monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v4-6dc675bf8c-82fg4   0/2     Pending   0          5d
```

Describe node:

```
Normal   Starting                 72s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     Starting kubelet.
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      71s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     70s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     Node h2860142.stratoserver.net status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    70s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     Node h2860142.stratoserver.net status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  70s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     Node h2860142.stratoserver.net status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Warning  InvalidDiskCapacity      54s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  54s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     Node h2860142.stratoserver.net status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    54s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     Node h2860142.stratoserver.net status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     54s                kubelet, h2860142.stratoserver.net     Node h2860142.stratoserver.net status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you share more information about your env? Its MicroK8s 1.18 or older? On which OS are you using this microk8s? Its your local env? Did you enable any addons before? Its new cluster or did you test something on it? Any steps to reproduce?

Answer (score 3):

I could find the solution for that issue. Well, that's not really a solution, but the answer is...I am hosting a **VPS-Server** on **STRATO** as hostingprovider. So in that case virtualisation is **not** possible. If I do not an upgrade to **dedicated Server**, I will never be able to run Kubernetes or Microk8s.

Comment: They say here Docker is running on e.g. ubuntu 20.04LTS  https://www.strato.de/faq/server/welche-server-und-betriebssysteme-sind-docker-ready/ . But seems like people are having still problems with kubernetes and docker swarm. So Chanigin provider is the only option here

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the service of `snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet`. only you should restart of service

```sh
sudo systemctl restart snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet
sudo systemctl status snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [here](https://microk8s.io/docs/install-alternatives) steps when using ZFS filesystem

Stop microk8s

```
microk8s stop
```

Remove old state of containerd:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/containerd
```

Configure containerd to use ZFS:

Edit the file `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd-template.toml`
replacing `snapshotter = "overlayfs"` with `snapshotter = "zfs"`

Create new zfs dataset for containerd to use:

```
zfs create -o mountpoint=/var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs $POOL/containerd
```

Restart microk8s:

```
microk8s start
```

Comment: I get this error = ```modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0```

Comment: I am not using a ZFS from what I can tell - I do, however, have a large ext4 volume and having this "invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem" issue

Comment: Also when I run the ZFS command I just get "cannot create '/containerd': leading slash in name"

Comment: No where in the question did the user say they were using ZFS.   I think you should remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when the hostname of the server had CAPITAL letters.
We created a new VM with a lowercase name, and we did not see the problem.

From what I could tell, it had to do with certificate access and the machine names not matching.